# Custom CKEditor plugin button not showing

Tags: ckeditor

Feel like I should have been able to track this one down already. I need to create a custom plugin for CKEditor (I'm using 4.3.1). To get started I used the guide found here (http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/plugin_sdk_sample_1). I downloaded the code and put it in my ckeditor\plugins folder. So, now I have ckeditor\plugins\abbr. I'm not sure what I'm doing, but the button is not showing in the toolbar. The code is below. My questions are, where should I define the "abbr" extra plugin? Do I do it in my _Edit.cshtml page where I'm defining stylesheetparser? Or put it in config.js? Given the setup below shouldn't the button show up next to the source button? Do I need to include it in config.js or does the plugin code take care of that?

Been doing a little playing around and it does show up if I use the full toolbar, but not when I customize it.

config.js

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {
    config.toolbar = 'MyToolbar';
    config.forcePasteAsPlainText = true;
    //config.extraPlugins = 'abbr';
    config.ignoreEmptyParagraph = 'true'
  config.toolbar_MyToolbar =
    [
    { name: 'document', items: ['Preview', 'Print'] },
    { name: 'clipboard', items: ['Cut', 'Copy', 'PasteText', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo'] },
    { name: 'editing', items: ['Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll', '-', 'SpellChecker', 'Scayt'] },
    { name: 'basicstyles', items : [ 'Bold','Italic','Subscript','Superscript','-','RemoveFormat' ] },
        '/',
    { name: 'insert', items: ['Table', 'SpecialChar'] },
    { name: 'styles', items : [ 'Styles'] }

    , { name: 'source', items: ['Source', '-', 'abbr'] }
    ];
};
```

_Edit.cshtml

```
 @Html.TextAreaFor(e => e.Narrative, 10, 10, null)
 <script type="text/javascript">
     CKEDITOR.replace('Narrative', {
         extraPlugins: 'stylesheetparser,abbr',

         // Stylesheet for the contents.
         contentsCss: '@Href("~/content/"+@Model.CssFile)',
         stylesheetParser_skipSelectors: '',
         disableNativeSpellChecker: false,

         // Do not load the default Styles configuration.
         stylesSet: [],
         height: '600px',
         width: '100%'
         });
 </script>
```

plugin.js

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'abbr', {

// Register the icons.
icons: 'abbr',

// The plugin initialization logic goes inside this method.
init: function( editor ) {

    // Define an editor command that opens our dialog.
    editor.addCommand( 'abbr', new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand( 'abbrDialog' ) );

    // Create a toolbar button that executes the above command.
    editor.ui.addButton( 'Abbr', {

        // The text part of the button (if available) and tooptip.
        label: 'Insert Abbreviation',

        // The command to execute on click.
        command: 'abbr',
        // The button placement in the toolbar (toolbar group name).
        toolbar: 'source'
    });

    // Register our dialog file. this.path is the plugin folder path.
    CKEDITOR.dialog.add( 'abbrDialog', this.path + 'dialogs/abbr.js' );
}
});
```

Comment: Found the issue (with some help from CKEditor support). I was going to delete my question, but just in case someone runs across this in the future I'll leave it. I'm using "Item by Item" configuration (http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_toolbar) which means I do have to define where the button lives in my configuration. The plugin is called "abbr" but the button itself is called "Abbr" - with a capital A. When I changed the line in my config file to "{ name: 'source', items: ['Source', '-', 'Abbr'] }" it worked. Case matters. Lesson learned.

Comment: lesson learned here as well. thnx.

Comment: Thank you very much for researching! It helps me. It needs to add to documentation state.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was looking for the solution for hours... It should be mentionned clearly somewhere.